# Solving ODE using Green's function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

How do I solve ODEs for the Green's function, for the given homogeneous boundary or initial conditions:

> $$G″ - \kappa_0^22 G(x, x_0) = \delta(x - x_0),\quad G = 0\text{ for }x = a\text{ and }x = b,\quad\kappa_0\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: What have you tried? See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting tips.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> I'll assume that
>   
>   $\ds{\partiald[2]{\mrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}{x} - k_{0}^{2}\,\mrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}} =
> \delta\pars{x - x_{0}}\,,\qquad
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> \ds{\mrm{G}\pars{a,x_{0}} = \,\mrm{G}\pars{b,x_{0}} = 0}
> \\[2mm]
> \ds{k_{0} > 0\quad \mbox{and}\quad x_{0} \in \pars{a,b}}
> \end{array}\right.}$.

\begin{align}
\mrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}} & =
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{A\sinh\pars{k_{0}\bracks{x - a}}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x < x_{0}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{B\sinh\pars{k_{0}\bracks{b - x}}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x > x_{0}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
$\ds{A}$ and $\ds{B}$ are determined with:

1. $\ds{\mrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}$ is *continuos* at $\ds{x = x_{0}}$.
2. $\ds{\mrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}$ satisfies
   $\ds{\left.\partiald{\mrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}{x}
   \right\vert_{\ x\ =\ x_{0}^{-}}^{\ x\ =\ x_{0}^{+}}\,\,\, = 1}$

Namely,
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\ds{\sinh\pars{k_{0}\bracks{x_{0} - a}}\, A} & \ds{-} & 
\ds{\sinh\pars{k_{0}\bracks{b - x_{0}}}\, B} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}
\\[2mm]
\ds{-k_{0}\cosh\pars{k_{0}\bracks{x_{0} - a}}\, A} & \ds{-} & 
\ds{k_{0}\cosh\pars{k_{0}\bracks{b - x_{0}}}\, B} & \ds{=} & \ds{1}
\end{array}\right.
$$